# what is the best way to retrieve data from other website?

Tags: php, xml, curl, file-get-contents

I want to get a table from other website (the table is being updated daily) and I want it to be shown in my website just not in the same arrangement as it has in the original website.

So I got the table using curl and strstr() but edit the whole table using string functions just seems pointless. I'm sure there is a much easier way doing this.

Maybe there is a way to create the original table in xml format that I'll be able to play with the structure more easily?

Thank you very much!

Comment: email the owner of the website and ask him/her to provide a feed.

Comment: Well this is about an information from the government's website. I'm doubt they will agree to create a feed just for me... :)

Comment: If it's information from a government website, then they might already provide a feed

Comment: No they didn't. they just gives the option to download an Excel file with the information. But I want the information to be updated at my own website...

Comment: In what format is the excel file? Php has lots of functions/classes that read excel files. Maybe you can give a link to the page?

Comment: This is the page: http://www.votes-19.gov.il/nationalresults
It is about national results of the elections.
I've already took the table using curl and string functions... wondering if there is an easy way to get 2 useless columns out of this table

Comment: use cURL to fetch the data, simplexml/dom to process the data.

Comment: It's actually a CSV file, so retrieve the file using curl, and read it via PHP's fgetcsv() function

Comment: @TzahiSerruya you should also cache the content locally for a short duration (eg 1 hour) to reduce requests to the third party website.

Comment: @Scuzzy - from the look of the data, it's probably a one-off.... election results aren't normally updated that frequently

Comment: @Scuzzy I've already built the php and it takes the table from the third party's website and saves it as a local file on the server every couple of minutes using CronJobs.
This is the output file http://www.webleader.co.il/websites/rotter/data/current.htm

I'm checking now how to use simplexml in order of getting rid of some columns.

Comment: @MarkBaker , The CSV files can't help me because they don't have the same data as the original table has (and I don't need this data, just the table...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a crude example of how you might consume the table (only to echo out another table), Below I'm using SimpleXML and xpath to search the document for the  element that has a class of Table Data and looping through all the TR's and putting some special conditions to deal with the  and  blocks that exist

Obvious downside is if the third party website's layout changes, your code will stop functioning.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.votes-19.gov.il/nationalresults'); // or use curl
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

echo '<!doctype html><html><head><style type="text/css">body{direction: rtl;}</style></head><body><table>';
if($trxpath = $xml->xpath('//table[@class="TableData"]/tr'))
{
  foreach($trxpath as $tr)
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>' . $tr->th . '</th>';
    foreach($tr->td as $td)
    {
      if($td->div)
        echo '<td>' . $td->div . '</td>';
      else
        echo '<td>' . $td . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
echo '</table></body></html>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time to solve my problem! I appreciate it!